# getting permission denied error on downloading and saving images from url

Tags: python

I'm trying to make web scraper that downloads images from searched keywords. The code works completely fine until it has to download that image from extracted URL

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import urllib

search = raw_input("search for images: ")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://wwww.bing.com/images/search", params=params)
dir_name = search.replace(" ", "_").lower()

if not os.path.isdir(dir_name):
    os.makedirs(dir_name)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for items in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(items.attrs["href"])
    print "Getting: ", items.attrs["href"]
    title = items.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    urllib.urlretrieve(items.attrs["href"], "./scraped_images/")
```

OUTPUT:

```
search for images: cats
Getting:  http://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2755/4353908962_2a0003aebf.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/qazii/PycharmProjects/WebScraping/exm.py", line 21, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve(items.attrs["href"], "./scraped_images/")
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\urllib.py", line 249, in retrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './scraped_images/'
```

Comment: They are probably blocking this to prevent scraping or hotlinking.

Comment: Does this scrapped_images folder exists? Or the software is still to create it?

Comment: @AlexanderSantos yes this folder exists

Comment: @CMMCD actually I'm following a tutorial and he scrapped images with the same method, but now it's showing error when i try to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to save the image to a "file" named `./scraped_images/`. Since this is a *directory* and not a file, you get a permissions error (you can't open a directory with write permissions). Instead, try saving to a specific file name.

```
urllib.urlretrieve(items.attrs["href"], os.path.join("./scrapped_images", title))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. now it's working perfectly. Thanks again :)